# Adding Spring Cloud Config to boot app causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError by adding unwanted jar to class path

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix, nosuchmethoderror, jsr311

I have a working Spring boot app.  I changed the application to read its configuration from Spring Cloud Config server.  I added bootstrap.properties and the following dependencies to the pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The version of spring cloud is 2020.0.4.  The app successfully retrieves its configuration from the config server.  However, the endpoints fail with the following error:

```
in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])'] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])'
```

I have run the boot application in debug mode to see what the Tomcat classpath is.  Prior to adding Spring Cloud Config , there was only

`jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar`

on the classpath.  However after adding the config server dependencies

`jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar`
is showing up on the Tomcat classpath before the Jakarta library and hence why this is happening.

I am not sure why the addition of Spring Cloud Config dependencies to my pom and adding a property file would cause this addition to the classpath.

I am running/building the app using mvn spring-boot:run.

How do I fix this issue?

Update:  it seems that the `jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar` gets pulled in by `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is the added dependency changed the class path order. You need to exclude the offending dependency

Comment: Further investigation: jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar gets pulled in by spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client.  But I need this dependency.  Otherwise I can't discover the config server.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to my pom.xml and I can reach my application endpoints successfully.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```